# keytouch package is missing in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, keyboard-layout

keytouch missing in database for Ubuntu 13.10. How can it be installed in Ubuntu 13.10 for Microsoft Office keyboard support?

Comment: I see that it has been removed for [all releases newer than 10.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/keytouch/+publishinghistory). Only the editor package is currently available.